# C++ Qt - opening text file operation failure

Tags: c++, qt, text, qml

I'm using Qt to develop my C++ application using QML as well.

Here's my code

```
QFile inputFile("data.txt");
//QFile inputFile("/:data.txt");
qDebug() << "Hello:";
if (!inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    qDebug() << "Wasn't ready:";
}
else{
    qDebug() << "Txt file ready:";
    QTextStream in(&inputFile);
    while ( !in.atEnd() )
    {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        qDebug() << "message: " << line;
    }
}
```

I was wondering why it doesn't work. The console always prints "Wasn't ready". 
Please help.

Comment: Is there a file called `data.txt` that is readable in the current directory of your executable?

Answer (score 1):

In the error handling block where you do `qDebug() << "Wasn't ready:";` you should call `inputFile.error()` and print out the returned value to get more details of what went wrong.

It might also be an idea to start the program with printing out the current directory, to make sure that the file is searched for in the correct location.